# Re-delivering non acknowledged message to the same consumer without closing channel or broker restart

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Consider the following scenario:

- A message is put on a queue. The queue is declared to be durable.
- A single consumer gets the message from the queue but do not acknowledge it. A basic consume was performed on the message by the consumer. At this moment, I can see in rabbitmq management website that the ready_message count goes down by 1 and messages_unacknowledged count goes up by 1.
- After that, a basic reject with requeue was performed on the message's delivery tag/info. message_ready and message_unacknowledged count still same here on the queue.

Now, I performed a basic recover on the same consumer on the same channel. However, even after executing the basic recover and adding some sleep did not make the the message_unacknowledged count go down by 1 and message_ready count go up by 1.
Finally, when I close the current channel, I see the message_unacknowledged count go down by 1 and message_ready count go up by 1.
My question is, Is it not possible to do a recover the unacknowledged messages on the same consumer unless you close your current channel in RabbitMQ?

Comment: Your description sounds correct so perhaps you have an error in your code.

Comment: I have used the SimpleAmqpClient's implementation for rabblitmq client (source: https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient). So,  in my declaration the queue was configured with autoack set to false. A simple put and get operation was performed on the durable queue I created and the status of the queue was observed in rabbitmq managerment website. I was gearing towards whether the concept of recovering an unack'd message without closing the current channel correct or not.